# Django use the same variable in different functions

Tags: python, django

What I am trying to do is, fetching data from a third party app and show it on the page. I will get the data in `get_context_data` function and use the same data in `get_initial` method as well. I could not manage to do that. Is there any way to do that?

**Example Code**

```
class UpdateView(generic.FormView):
    template_name = 'test.html'
    form_class = myForm
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        MYVARIABLE = fetch_data_from_3rd_party_app()
        context["MYVARIABLE"] = MYVARIABLE
        return context

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()

        # I want to assign MYVARIABLE.data to initial["data"] here.
        initial["data"] = MYVARIABLE

        return initial
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of options

First there's the approach that the generic views from Django take and store the variable on `self`, assign it at some early point in the request (dispatch, get, post, etc) so that it's available to whoever needs it

```
class UpdateView(generic.FormView):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.myvariable = fetch_data_from_3rd_party_app()
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["MYVARIABLE"] = self.myvariable
        return context

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial["data"] = self.myvariable
        return initial
```

I'm quite partial to using a [cached property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property), assigning to `self` outside of `__init__` feels slightly wrong to me (although there is nothing really wrong with it)

```
from django.utils.functional import cached_property

class UpdateView(generic.FormView):

    @cached_property
    def myvariable(self):
        return fetch_data_from_3rd_party_app()
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["MYVARIABLE"] = self.myvariable
        return context

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial["data"] = self.myvariable
        return initial
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I really liked this `cached_property`